# Form with radio buttons submit to mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm beginner in php and mysql and I need your help in one situation.
I have a form with radio buttons, actually is a star rating system and I want to submit the form through an ajax call to a mysql database.
I don't know how to make the ajax call and the php for inserting in mysql. Please help!

My code is:

```
<div class="Clear">&nbsp;</div>
<form id="form1">

        Question 1:bla bla bla

   <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="5"/>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 2:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="5"/>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 3:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="5"/>
   </div>
 <br>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 4:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="1" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="2" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="3" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="4" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="5" />
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 5:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="5"/>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 6:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="1" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="2" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="3" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="4" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="5" />
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit scores!" />  </td>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What is not working? What are you trying to do? Please explain more.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript or PHP code you can show us? That way we can help you much easier.

Comment: I don''t know how to do the ajax call and the php:(

Comment: @user1820705 - So you have to explain this in your question in details.

Comment: learn jQuery or AJAX first, implement some code then post.

Comment: If you don't want to help better don't loose your time posting here.

Comment: Hope this tutorials will be helpful.
If you have jquery:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
If you dont have jquery(pure javascript): http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all ans with serialize function and pass to ans_file.php.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
 var ans=$(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: "ans_file.php",
  data:ans
 }).done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
 return false;
});
```

I have some problems:
I made this php and is not inserting nothing, can you please tell me if I am missing 
something?
Thanks!

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "stars";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$question1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question1']);
$question2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question2']);
$question3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question3']);
$question4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question4']);
$question5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question5']);
$question6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question6']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (answers) VALUES ('$question1','$question2','$question3','$question4','$question5','$question6')");
echo "<h1>Thank You !</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: we don't even know if he has jQuery

Comment: Botond Balázs: I have jquery, i specified that i want to submit it through an ajax call

Comment: remove if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{} and try !!